Create a ChoiceField , linked to a OneToMany property on a Doctrine Entity with EasyAdmin
I'm working on an application builded with Symfony 7.1 and EasyAdmin 4.10 with 3 Entities: Mission, SkillCategory and Skill
The relationship between Mission and Skills is ManyToMany
I just want to be able to add a SkillField into my MissionCrudController, BUT, i want to be able to specify the order_by of each Skill, the way i can with the Symfony ChoiceType, i tried with this :
In my MissionCrudController :
$skillsField = ChoiceField::new('skills', t('ui.mission.skills'))
->setFormType(SkillType::class);
                $categories = $this->skillCategoryRepository->findAll();
                $choices = [];

                foreach ($categories as $category) {
                    $skills = $category->getSkills();

                    if ($skills) {
                        $group = [];
                        /** @var Skill $skill */
                        foreach ($skills as $skill) {
                            $group[$skill->getName()] = $skill->getId();
                        }
                        $choices[$category->getName()] = $group;
                    }
                }
                return $choices;
            });


Or with this code :
$skillsField = ChoiceField::new('skills', t('ui.mission.skills'))
            ->allowMultipleChoices(true)
            ->setFormType(SkillType::class)
        ;

With the following SkillTypeField :

final class SkillType extends AbstractType
{
    public function __construct(private readonly SkillRepository $skillRepository)
    {
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', ChoiceType::class,
                [
                    'group_by' => 'category',
                    'choice_value' => 'id',
                    'choices' => $this->skillRepository->findAll(),
                    'choice_label' => fn(Skill $skill) => $skill->getName(),
                    'multiple' => true,
                    'data_class' => Skill::class
                ]
            );
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Skill::class
        ]);
    }
}

But i keep getting different errors, i think what i'm trying to do is somehow kind of basic, so i must be doing something wrong,...
If anyone can give me a helpful hand, that would be really great, cause i'm really stuck, if the way to do so is to use AssociationField, then, how to do so with the group_by parameter ?!!
I tried to get a ChoiceField with easyAdmin,getting all data from a repository, grouped by category, but i can't figure out how to do so, whatever i'm trying to do

Ok, so, for aynone who might be interested, the solution was quite easy, and i apologize for not having thought about it before, you just have to use an AssociationField with a group_by, this way :
$skillsField = AssociationField::new('skills', t('ui.mission.skills'))
        ->setFormTypeOption('group_by','category')
    ;

That's all folks, sorry for the disturbance, have a nice day !
